# How can I use a double arrow cursor in java?

Tags: java, swing

The image shows the `N_RESIZE_CURSOR`, `S_RESIZE_CURSOR`, `E_RESIZE_CURSOR`, and `W_RESIZE_CURSOR` options in Java.  It also shows the normal double arrow cursor used elsewhere.  These are screenshots of a video recording, so the quality is a bit lacking.

[image]

The double arrow cursors were taken in a Java application (eclipse), so I know it is possible.

I've found [this](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/types/Cursor.html), but I'd rather not add in a dependency for something Java should be able to do.

Comment: What's the context? A Swing application? Something else? ...and for the record, Eclipse uses a separate set of UI components – they're not built in to Java. http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-ui/

Comment: Swing application, Cursor.set()

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310404/java-swing-custom-cursor-is-invisible)